# SQL Adapter Invocation failure in IBM MobileFirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to insert data to a database using a SQL Adapter in IBM mobilefirst platform, however my code reaches the failure function...

main.js:

```
function insertData(){

  alert("Function InsertData called");
  var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value.toString();
  var lname = document.forms["form1"]["lname"].value.toString();
  var email = document.forms["form1"]["email"].value.toString();
  var pwd = document.forms["form1"]["pwd"].value.toString();
  // alert("fname"+fname);

  var invocationData = {
    adapter: 'SQLDemo',
    procedure: 'procedure4',
    parameters:[fname,lname,email,pwd]
  };

  var options = {
    onSuccess : InsertDataSuccess,
    onFailure : InsertDataFailed,
    timeout : 30000
  };
  WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}

function InsertDataSuccess(result){
  alert("Success");
  WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
}

function InsertDataFailed(result){
  alert("Failure");
  WL.Logger.debug("Retrieve success" +  JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

Adapter'sSQLDemo-impl.js:

```
var procedure4Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("INSERT INTO INNOVATION (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
function procedure4(fname,lname,email,password) {
  return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
      preparedStatement : procedure4Statement, 
      parameters : [fname,lname,email,password] 
  });
}
```

Comment: And what is the error you get in InsertDataFailed...? What is the "result"? Also, add the implementation of "procedure4".

Comment: It is going to onFailure function                                                                                         var procedure4Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("INSERT INTO INNOVATION (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

//var procedure3Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from INNOVATION where FIRSTNAME=? and id=?");

function procedure4(fname,lname,email,password) {
 
 return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
  preparedStatement : procedure4Statement,
  parameters : [fname,lname,email,password]
 });
}

Comment: 1) obviously please edit the question with the code - not in comments. 2) I am asking what does it print in "result".

Comment: Also change "result" to "result.errorMsg" in InsertDataFailed().

Comment: The result.errorMsg is returning null and If I give empty values in my form then it is returning success message

Comment: @vinodh, can you provide the logs at server side.

Comment: @dhineshsundar Could you please let me know where could I found logs at server side in Mobile First Server .Thanks

Comment: @vinodh, Select the _MobileFirst Development Server_ in Console View.

Comment: I tested the code end-to-end, and it works (checked in the database). The server logs are indeed required. You can find the messages.log file in <eclipse-workspace>\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\logs\ (or as @dhineshsundar mentioned, in the MobileFirst Development Server view of the Console view in Eclipse.

Comment: @IdanAdar00000651 SystemErr                                                            R 27276020  WorklightManagementPU-derby  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-652] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.

Comment: Please upload to whole file somewhere, like Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0t7nvlhqo2h4vo/DemoProject.rar?dl=0

Comment: Vinod... we asked for the full messages.log file from the location specified above. Not your project(!).

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8e0911z91azozf/messages.log?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the messages.log file:

> E FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project
>   DemoProject]SQLDemo/SqlStatementFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project
>   DemoProject] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
>   SQLERRMC=from;AJAX set FIRSTNAME=?;.., DRIVER=3.61.75. Performed
>   query: update AJAX set FIRSTNAME=? from AJAX where id=? FWLSE0101E:
>   Caused by:  [project
>   DemoProject]com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
>   SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=from;AJAX set FIRSTNAME=?;..,
>   DRIVER=3.61.75java.lang.RuntimeException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104,
>   SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=from;AJAX set FIRSTNAME=?;.., DRIVER=3.61.75.
>
> ...
>
> Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance vinod is invalid for the
>   requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

And there are more exceptions below it.

Make sure in your database scheme that you're actually expecting strings, not limiting value length too much, etc.

Comment: Idan Adar my adapter working and whenever i am calling my adapter individually the resultent in the browser like                                                                    {
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "updateStatementResult": {
      "updateCount": 1
   }
}                                                                                                                        means  no problem with database

Comment: Yes, your adapter is working, your database is misconfigured. Read the error. Google the error.

Comment: Idan Adar I'm successfully inserting data into database the thing is, my controller GOTO failure function, But Data is inserted.

Comment: The problem is like adapter is return null value, But data inserted.